# Host Images on my own server Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hosting, image-uploading

I have Users in my Rails application, and I need them to have Avatars. I had done some research and found a few very good gems like Paperclip and Carrierwave to handle uploads and such things. I know there are numerous image hosting solutions, but they are paid. I have my own VPS on Ubuntu, so I thought I might use it. It would be the same one for hosting my Rails application. Is this possible? If it is, how hard it is to make it work?

Comment: This is the most common way to store your files, rails does it by default! :)

Comment: @dpedoneze haha is it possible? so I can put images in static assets?

Comment: It depends how you're hosting - Heroku won't allow you to write to the `public/assets/` folder, only the `tmp/` folder (and this isn't permanent storage). You can use S3 image hosting on AWS for free or rather cheaply. Or maybe store images as base64 in your database.

Comment: @maxpleaner im not hosting on heroku, im hosting on digital temple. what can i do?

Comment: If you're using your own VPN it's the same as your localhost server (you can upload files and show them on your localhost). Some hosts doesn't allow you to store files (like @maxpleaner said).